# How to specify selecting field using with lazy operator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to specify selecting field using with lazy operator?

```
Order::with("country", "pacient")->get();
```

How to specify selecting fields for model `Order` and depended relations like:

```
order.id, country.name, pacient.name,...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be selected specific columns in eager load and it will work

```
Order::with('country:id,name', 'pacient:id,name')->get();
```

just make sure you add relation id when you fetch relational columns

if you want fluent query
then

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'orders.country_id')
    ->join('pacient', 'pacient.id', '=', 'orders.pacient_id')
    ->select('order.id', 'country.name', 'pacient.name')
     ->get();
```

Comment: I consider easy to use native queries using DB::select

Comment: Is it possible to specify fields in relation model? Here: ` return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'Orders_Id', 'Id');`

Comment: yes you can used like return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'Orders_Id', 'Id')->select('name');
more info => https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a more granular and "laravel" way: using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources).

## Generation

```php
php artisan make:resource OrderResource
```

## Customization

**app/Http/Resources/OrderResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'order_id' => $this->id,
            'country_name' => $this->country->name,
            'patient' => $this->patient->name,
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

## Use

In a controller, you can do:

**app/Http/Controllers/MyCoolController.php**

```php
use App\Http\Resources\OrderResource;

// ...

public function myCoolMethod()
{
    // get your posts:
    $orders = Order::all();

    return OrderResource::collection($posts);
}
```

Comment: You know it is possible, but let's imagine, that table contains more then 100 fields, they will be in SELECT operator. In my case I want to reduce complexity of query and increase selection performance. You suggested a way when all  table fields will be retrieved in query.